# retrieve data from multi text field in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, fxml

i'm working on an application where i should retrieve data from text fields that i created dynamically in a javaFX controller after that the user decides the number of the text fields. since in the first view i have only one textfield, i did retrieve it easily with no problem but i just have no clue about how to do it when the text field are dynamically created from the controller.

i tried to use the textfield.getText(); but it's not working.

this is my code:

```
public void handleButtonActionNext(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{

        String t = textField.getText();
        IntegerStringConverter a = new IntegerStringConverter();
        this.i = a.fromString(t);

        Node node = (Node) event.getSource();
        Stage stage = (Stage) node.getScene().getWindow();
        Scene scene = stage.getScene();
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("ProcessusTimeExec.fxml"));
        Parent root = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
        scene.setRoot(root); 

        gridPane = (GridPane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ProcessusTimeExec.fxml"));
        Scene secondScene = new Scene(gridPane);
        gridPane.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));

        this.listTextField = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int n=1; n<=i;n++){
                this.label = new Label("execution Time "+n);

                GridPane.setConstraints(label, 0, n+2);
                GridPane.setConstraints(textField, 1, n+2);
                gridPane.getChildren().add(textField);
                gridPane.getChildren().add(label);
            }

            stage.setScene(secondScene);
    }
```

here in this Handlevent in the same controller i'm trying to retrieve the data in order to send it to the logic part of my project.

```
public void handleButtonActionAlgo(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{

        Node node = (Node) event.getSource();
        Stage stage = (Stage) node.getScene().getWindow();
        Scene scene = stage.getScene();
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Algo.fxml"));

        Parent root = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
        scene.setRoot(root);

        // retrieve the data from the textFields      
    }
```

the button that takes those actions is in the FXML file.

Answer (score 1):

Something like :

```
       TextField textField[] = new TextField[...]; 

      for(int n=1; n<=i;n++) {
            textField[n] = new TextField("input "+n);
            gridPane.getChildren().add(textField[n]);
        }
```

You can test by printing them using `.getText()`

```
    for(int n=1; n<=i;n++) {System.out.println(textField[n].getText());}
```